# Docusign: Ability to correct/VOID and resend documents from Salesforce

Tags: apex, community, docusign

When an agent sends a document from Salesforce using 'Send with Docusign', they enter information by tagging or manually typing into the document. If the client can't find the document/something needs fixing to sign/don't get it in their email, then we need to resend it or invalidate the document if the agent sent the wrong document

The current solution is for us to log into docusign to do all of the above. It cannot be seen by the agent that it has been resubmitted, canceled or corrected anywhere in the solution unless the person making the change posts it to a case.

Is it possible to have this information integrated into Salesforce so that it is visible to the agent, and do all above in Salesforce?

Comment: Yes. Look into Docusign's out of the box integration with Salesforce, it does this.

Comment: Thanks for the respons - I have no luck in finding that out-of-the-box integration can do this in salesforce. Do you have a link?

Comment: [eSignature for SF](https://support.docusign.com/s/document-item?language=en_US&rsc_301=&bundleId=srl1586134368658&topicId=sin1597260513697.html&_LANG=enus). The product itself can be seen [here](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000001taX4EAI&tab=e)